# Ansible List Variable and Select Filter to ignore matched items

Tags: regex, ansible, ninja, ansible-filter

I have a variable `dir_lst_raw` in an ansible playbook whose value is a *list* as shown below:

```
"dir_lst_raw": [
        "/path1/dir1/user",
        "/path2/dir2/admin",
        "/path3/dir3/user.ansible_backup_2020-03-16",
        "/path1/dir1/config.ansible_backup_2020-03-16",
        "/path2/dir2/dir3/somefile"
      ]
```

I need to remove all the lines containing `.ansible_backup_` and save to another variable as a *list*.
I've googled for regex and tried to *not match the pattern with the select filter* as below:

```
  - set_fact:
      dir_lst: "{{ dir_lst_flt_r | select('match','(^.ansible_backup_)+') | list }}"
```

but the new variable `dir_lst` turned out as an empty list. I am expecting `dir_lst` as below:

```
"dir_lst_raw": [
        "/path1/dir1/user",
        "/path2/dir2/admin",
        "/path2/dir2/dir3/somefile"
     ]
```

Could somebody please suggest how can I get it done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Q: ***"Remove all the lines containing `.ansible_backup_`"***

A: You can either use the simple [test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) ***search***. Quote:

> search succeeds if it finds the pattern anywhere within the string.

```yaml
  dir_lst: "{{ dir_lst_raw|reject('search', dir_lst_search)|list }}"
  dir_lst_search: '\.ansible_backup_'
```

or you can use the [test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) ***regex***. Quote:

> regex works like search, but regex can be configured to perform other tests as well by passing the match_type keyword argument ...

```yaml
  dir_lst: "{{ dir_lst_raw|reject('regex', dir_lst_regex)|list }}"
  dir_lst_regex: '^(.*)\.ansible_backup_(.*)$'
```

Both options give the same result

```yaml
  dir_lst:
    - /path1/dir1/user
    - /path2/dir2/admin
    - /path2/dir2/dir3/somefile
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    dir_lst_raw:
      - /path1/dir1/user
      - /path2/dir2/admin
      - /path3/dir3/user.ansible_backup_2020-03-16
      - /path1/dir1/config.ansible_backup_2020-03-16
      - /path2/dir2/dir3/somefile

    dir_lst1: "{{ dir_lst_raw|reject('search', dir_lst_search)|list }}"
    dir_lst_search: '\.ansible_backup_'

    dir_lst2: "{{ dir_lst_raw|reject('regex', dir_lst_regex)|list }}"
    dir_lst_regex: '^(.*)\.ansible_backup_(.*)$'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: dir_lst1
    - debug:
        var: dir_lst2
```