# How to pass a variable using match filter in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-filter

I am trying to list VMs from the vcenter, filtering VM names which starts with `linTest` and `winTest`. How can I pass `linTest|winTest` as a variable in the code below?

```yaml
  - name: Gather all registered virtual machines
    vmware_vm_info:
      hostname: '{{ vc_host }}'
      username: '{{ vc_user }}'
      password: '{{ vc_pass }}'
      validate_certs: False
    delegate_to: localhost
    register: vminfo

  - set_fact:
      vm_hostname: "{{ vminfo.virtual_machines | map(attribute='guest_name')|select('match', '^(linTest|winTest)')| list }} "

  - debug:
      var: vm_hostname
```

Comment: I don't see any attempt to pass the required info as a variable in the above code sample. Please provide an [mcve](/help/mcve) showing what you have done so far, the result/error you get and a description of what you expect instead. You should also read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) before you proceed with [editing your question](/posts/72010777/edit). As a side question, are you really expecting a different outcome when [posting the exact same question](/questions/71999155/set-variables-for-match-filter-in-ansible?noredirect=1#comment127222521_71999155)?

Comment: Since your question seems to be almost a duplicate of [Can variables be used as Ansible filter parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992278/can-variables-be-use-as-ansible-filter-parameters), the credits should go the answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you like to pass a variable regluar expression to the filter. To do so you could use an approach like

```yaml
...
vars:

  REGEX: '^(linTest|winTest)'

tasks:

- set_fact:
      vm_hostname: "{{ vminfo.virtual_machines | map(attribute='guest_name') | select('match', REGEX) | list }}"
...
```

in short `select('match', REGEX)`.

**Further Q&A**

- [How to use a variable inside a variable definition that uses filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33115467/6771046)
- [Ansible ... select filter ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60721624/6771046)
- [Can variables be use as Ansible filter parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66997627/6771046)